# ¿Que función cumple el parámetro session_cache_limiter con el session_start?

Tags: php, session

Estoy realizando mi aplicación web con sesión de usuario. He configurado tiempo de caducidad y todo ese cuento.

Leyendo la página de [PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/function.session-cache-limiter.php), me encuentro con que esta variable juega un papel importante, pero no logro entender en que afecta a la sesión del usuario logueado.
Según lo que entiendo es que de acuerdo al parámetro envíado "public", "private" o "nocache" Se permite o no la visualización de los datos almacenados en la caché.

**¿Estoy en lo correcto?**

**¿Afecta en algo al tiempo de caducidad de la sesión?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No**, no estás en lo correcto ya que solamente sirve para indicar el grado de visualización que se podrá tener desde el lado del cliente de las **cabeceras** sobre el estado de la caché, pero **no de la información** y **no**, no afecta al tiempo de caducidad de la sesión del usuario.

Simplemente indicas en tu aplicación web las cabeceras que se enviarán al cliente (y que este podrá examinar) sobre el estado de la caché.

Comment: Vale, ya entendí perfectamente. Gracias.